# Does apple allow modifying UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, uialertview, appstore-approval

I found a sample on github in which A tableView is added inside UIAlertView. SO I would like to know that will my app rejected if I use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a username and password filed in UIAlertView and its get accepted! So I think added a table view will also get accepted!

Comment: yes sure, i also have seen many apps in app store who have change the uialert but are on app store.

Comment: @Rahul, Apple allows modify the uiAlertview. i have also added progress bar in this. and apple also approve this. thx

Comment: iamsaurabhsharma [at] gmail [dot] com, saurabhsharma [at] live [dot] com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add numnber of textFields to the UIAlertView and its accepted.so may be no problem with tableview.